# Set title in browser for Ionic apps

Tags: html, ionic-framework, browser

I am developing an Ionic App that will run as a web app on browsers too.

In html, I have the following code:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Login</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

I thought that the ion-title tag was enough to change the title on the browser tab, but it seems it isn't.
It remains "Ionic App".
How can I change it?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check your "index.html" file in the src folder. You would see the "title" html tag. Change it there and it would reflect.

Comment: How can I make the title change according to the different visited pages?

Comment: @GiuseppeFaraci You can import App from ionic-angular and then load it into your component in the constructor. After that you can call app.SetTitle(string). See: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/app/App/

Answer (score 2):

Ionic 5 compatible solution

```
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

...

export class MyPage {

    constructor(private titleService: Title) {

        this.titleService.setTitle('Title');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution for **Ionic 5** + **React**:

Most likely you're working on files in `/src/` while the compiled files go into `www/`.

You may have wondered why `/src/index.html` or `/src/manifest.json` are not there or why they do have no effect if manually created.

Simply have a look into `/public/` there are your assets (App icon and Favicon for Web/PWA) and the blueprints of `index.html` and `manifest.json`.

`/public/index.html` looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Ionic App</title>

    <base href="/" />

    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"
    />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/icon/favicon.png" />

    <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Ionic App" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

I expected Ionic to take into account which App name you put into `/ionic.config.json`, but as you can see, it's hardcoded to be "Ionic App".